# QApplication is not defined in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt

I have wrote a C++ application in Xcode. To make it more friendly I will develop a user interface in Qt on MAC.

I have install Qt using qt-opensource-mac-x64-clang-5.3.2 as recommended by the qt project but I didn't find any way to make it linked with Xcode. include do not find QApplication or any other headers ?

Any procedure to enable Qt in Xcode ?

It's the first time for me in Qt.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you used the MacOSX installer in the .dmg downloaded file ?

Comment: Just develop your GUI in Qt Creator. Once the most important stuff has been set up you can pick-up the xcode project qmake creates in the build directory. Then Open that project in Xcode and integrate with your code